# Xamarin ModernHttpClient exception in Android

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have been using the plugin for quite a while and I never had any problems with it, but in my new project the OkHttp library of ModernHttpClient doesn't work for some reasons.

Each Http request throws the exception:

```
12-10 18:13:20.527 W/        ( 4373): Missing method Android.Runtime.JNIEnv::CallStaticObjectMethod(intptr,intptr,JValue*) in assembly Mono.Android.dll, referenced in assembly OkHttp.dll
mvx:Diagnostic: 17.36 Exception occurred in request: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod'.
12-10 18:13:20.537 I/mono-stdout( 4373): mvx:Diagnostic: 17.36 Exception occurred in request: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod'.

  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00138] in /Users/paul/code/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient/src/ModernHttpClient/Android/OkHttpNetworkHandler.cs:93 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-10 18:13:20.537 I/mono-stdout( 4373):   at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00138] in /Users/paul/code/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient/src/ModernHttpClient/Android/OkHttpNetworkHandler.cs:93 
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 17.36 Exception occurred in request: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod'.
  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00138] in /Users/paul/code/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient/src/ModernHttpClient/Android/OkHttpNetworkHandler.cs:93 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I would assume that recently you have updated to the newest Android? They have changed some stuff http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#GC-free-Method_Invocations so you probably need to recompile the library for Xam Android 5+

Comment: You mean recompile the library myself? I used to install it as a NuGet package. Also, I am not yet using Droid 5, I tried only target 18 and 19 (Android 4.3 and 4.4) and it didn't work. Also, I have not idea about how to recompile such library.

Comment: I have said Xamarin Android 5 not Android 5, this isn't the same thing. If you have updated recently your Xamarin, then you are probably running on Xamarin Android 5 (you can check this on Xamarin Studio). As Xamarin changed some things in their code, they broke some stuff and they say that you need to recompile the libraries that you use (either you or the author of the library)

Comment: So I ended up switching to Xamarin beta channel and updating to Xamarin version 3.9. After that it worked perfectly.